# Leer un byte específico de un fichero

Tags: c, archivo

Estoy tratando de leer el byte específico que ocupa la posición `position` del fichero y mostrar por pantalla dicho byte leído. `position` es un parámetro que siempre será un valor entero positivo mayor o igual que 1. Se asume que para leer el primer byte, se invoca al programa pasando un 1 en el parámetro.

```
int read_byte(int position) {
    int byte;
    int fd;
    char character;

    //Leer el byte position del fichero 
    if(read(fd, &character[pos], sizeof(char)) == 0) { 
    //if(lseek(fd, pos*sizeof(char), SEEK_CUR) == 0) { 
        printf("byte en la posicion %d = %c", position, character);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d leyendo el archivo a causa de %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return byte;
}
```

El error que estoy obteniendo es que no lee el byte tal y como tengo el código. También probé usando la función `lseek()` y reposicionar así el puntero y leer a partir de dicha posición. El codigo me arroja el error: `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para leer un archivo en una posición concreta debes abrirlo, moverte a dicha posición y leer los bytes que quieras.

```
char buffer[10];

// Abres el archivo
FILE* f = fopen("archivo", "rb");

// Te diriges a la posición deseada
fseek(f, posicion, SEEK_SET);

// Lees el archivo
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 10, f);

// Cierras el archivo
fclose(f);
```

Más información en https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io